# How to bring back my changes from some commits to the index?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

This is my top commit history:

```
5e1aaf7 final commit message
0356c0a add Toyota to Cars.txt
5498f0f add some cities to Cities.txt
e811024 add Cities.txt
```

I need to get changes from those commits to the index and commit them with one or more commits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Did you complete the rebase operation? Are you trying to undo the rebase?

Comment: I am learning about managing commits. I just need to bring back to the stage my changes from 3 last commits. I thought that `git rebase` is good, but it is not... `git checkout 0356c0a -- Cars.txt` is better? What does `--` and `Cars.txt` mean in this case?

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was unclear what you were asking. Can you update your question with what your Git commit history currently looks like?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt I updated the question

Comment: What would be useful is to explain why you're doing this.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Or is this just an exercise?

Comment: @Schwern This is only example, but I need to bring back my committed files, and be able commit them once again with different commits. I do not mean only change the name of commits, or reorder them. I just want to bring changes to the stage.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to redo the last four commits and work on them as one change.  `git reset --soft HEAD~4`

What's going on?  `git reset` moves the current branch label around to arbitrary positions (`git reset --`, confusingly, does something completely different) so `git reset HEAD~4` says to move the current branch back 4 commits.

`--soft`, `--hard`, `--mixed`, `--merge` and `--keep` control what happens to the index and working copy.  `--soft` leaves the index and working copy alone, so you'll still have the old HEAD on disk to work on.  `--hard` resets both the index and working copy to the new commit, sort of like `checkout`.  The rest I leave you to read the docs.

If you just wanted to squash them together, you'd do `git rebase -i HEAD~4` and use the `squash` command.

```
pick e811024 add Cities.txt
s 5498f0f add some cities to Cities.txt
s 0356c0a add Toyota to Cars.txt
s 5e1aaf7 final commit message
```

If you wanted to alter them individually, you would `rebase -i` and use the edit command.  Just know it may cause conflicts which you'll have to resolve.

```
e e811024 add Cities.txt
e 5498f0f add some cities to Cities.txt
e 0356c0a add Toyota to Cars.txt
e 5e1aaf7 final commit message
```

If you just wanted to alter the last commit, you would make the edits and do `git commit --amend`.  If you just wanted to redo the last commit, you would do `git reset --soft HEAD~`.  This moves the current branch back one commit but leaves the working copy alone.  I have it aliased to `redo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to retrieve a file from a specific commit, you can do this:

```
git checkout e811024 file/to/restore
```

This will checkout the file selected from commit `e811024`